# Documenting query parameters with API Blueprint

Tags: apiblueprint, apiary.io

I'm trying to document a query parameter in API Blueprint, but I'm not entirely sure if I have done it correctly. The resource looks like this:

```
DELETE http://baasar.apiary-mock.com/user/{appId}/{userId}
```

That request would deactivate the user while the following would delete the user object:

```
DELETE http://baasar.apiary-mock.com/user/{appId}/{userId}?force=true
```

This is the Blueprint markdown I have for this:

```
## User [/user/{appId}/{userId}]
Handle user objects

+ Parameters
    + appId (required, number, `1`) ... Application ID (`appId`)
    + userId (required, number, `1`) ... Numeric `userId` of the User object to manage

### Remove an User [DELETE]
+ Parameters
    + force (optional, boolean, `false`) ... Set to `true` to remove instead of deactivate

+ Response 204
```

However, when rendering this with Apiary I only see `force` in the list of parameters, but it is now shown in the example URL. Is that just me misunderstanding the GUI or should query parameters be documented in another way?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Your blueprint is perfectly fine, the problem is that the current Apiary documentation does not handle URI parameters correctly.

Could you please try the [new documentation](http://blog.apiary.io/2014/03/21/Re-API-Design-for-Humans/) out? It should handle URI parameters properly.

[image: URI Parameters]

#### Edit

The correct URI Template should be:

```
http://baasar.apiary-mock.com/user/{appId}/{userId}{?force}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I should have said that I use the new docs already. What confuses me is that there is no separation between "resource parameters" and "action parameters". So I think that it is not clear where to put `force` in the above example.

Comment: I have changed my resource definition to look like this `## User [/user/{appId}/{userId}?{force}=bool]` (I get an error in the Apiary syntax if `force` isn't present). That looks really good for the `DELETE` verb, but it makes my `GET` verb in the same resource look odd, as it does not support the `force` parameter.

Comment: You can see the desired behavior here with "list all notes" and "create note":
http://docs.queryparameters.apiary.io/?3ColumnDocumentation=1

There's just no documentation supporting the new URI template behavior, so no one knows how to use it. :-/

Comment: Fair point @james-h; I will add it to the specification https://github.com/apiaryio/api-blueprint/issues/79

Comment: @Baggz Off topic, but what theme is that?

Comment: @DeesOomens it's the 'documentation' view in Apiary

Answer (score 3):

My **curl** request:

```
curl -k -u username:password https://api.techie8.io/api/1.0/bits?bit_type=1
```

**Apiary blueprint:**

```
## Bits Collection [/bits?bit_type={bit_type}]

### List Latest bits [GET]

List all bits recently inserted into database.

+ Parameters
    + bit_type (number, optional, `1`) ... Type of bit to retrieve: 1: Bits, 2: Newsletter
```