# Apiary: Is there a way to define options for parameters?

Tags: parameters, arguments, apiblueprint, apiary.io, apiary

I would like to define options for Apiary parameters, I'm currently listing them in the description:

- measurement = `m` (optional, string, `m`) ... measurement e.g. m = meters, km = kilometers, yd = yards, mi = miles

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can enumerate the possible values of an URI query parameter and discuss it in the parameter discussion like so:

```
+ Parameters
    + measurement = `m` (optional, string) ... measurement units

        Any discussion here...

        e.g. explanation of **values** listed bellow are.

        + Values
            + `m`
            + `mi`
            + `yd`
```

Also see the [Documenting query parameters with API Blueprint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22845666/documenting-query-parameters-with-api-blueprint) question.

Answer (score 1):

You can define the optional parameters in the endpoint as below:

```
/api/data{?measurement}
```